# Set Backup Compression on SQL Server 2008R2 on by default

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, configuration, compression

I can't seem to find the option to set the server property that will enable compression on SQL database backup to be ON by default, so  I don't have to manually set it every time.

Can anyone point me at that please.

Comment: Here is a very good and details article on how to configure backup compression https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-configure-backup-compression/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technet Online says:

> To view or configure the backup compression default option
>
> In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
>
> Click the Database settings node.
>
> Under Backup and restore, Compress backup shows the current setting of the backup compression default option. This setting determines the server-level default for compressing backups, as follows:
>
> If the Compress backup box is blank, new backups are uncompressed by default.
>
> If the Compress backup box is checked, new backups are compressed by default.
>
> If you are a member of the sysadmin or serveradmin fixed server role, you can also change the default setting by clicking the Compress backup box.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933863.aspx

Comment: @Mac Vernon --  Does enabling this option need a restart of the SQL Server service ?

Comment: According to the MSDN article I linked to, it states [The setting takes effect immediately without restarting the server.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933863.aspx#Anchor_3)

Answer (score 5):

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'backup compression default', N'1'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

See [backup compression default Option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677250(v=sql.105).aspx) in the documentation.

This method can be easily included in a SQL Server setup script.